# Determine similarity of 2 lists considering list length

Tags: algorithm, similarity

I'm trying to calculate the similarity of two lists. Basically an edit distance (insert, delete, move) sort of like Damerau–Levenshtein. But the cost of each operation should take into account the list length. Moves should be proportional to the distance moved, and insert/delete should be proportional to the size of the list.

Basically a single-element difference in a short list is more significant than a single-element difference in a long list.

A few desired features:

1. The same operation on a longer list costs less than the same operation on a shorter list.
2. For moves, the longer the move, the higher the cost.
3. For moves, multiple smaller moves costs the same as one big move.
   *E.g. to move "a" to the end in `a,b,c` -> `b,c,a` costs the same as `a,b,c` -> `b,a,c` -> `b,c,a`.*
4. The longest move costs less than or equal to the cost of delete+insert.
5. A maximum cost can be computed given the length of two lists (which would be the cost to delete every element of the first list, and insert every element of the second list).

For example:

###### Move

```
# move "a" over 1, with list length 4
a,b,c,d -> b,a,c,d = 1/4

# move "a" over 3, with list length 4
a,b,c,d -> b,c,d,a = 3/4
```

###### Delete

```
# delete "a" with length 3
a,b,c -> b,c = 1+1/3 = 4/3

# delete "a" with length 4
a,b,c,d -> b,c,d = 1+1/4 = 5/4
```

###### Insert

```
# insert "a" with length 2
b,c -> a,b,c = 1+1/2 = 3/2

# insert "a" with length 3
b,c,d -> a,b,c,d = 1+1/3 = 4/3
```

For insert & delete, it's just a base cost of `1` plus `1 / list_len`. This is to make it satisfy features #1 & #4 above.

Fore my use case, I also have a guarantee that each element of the list is unique. It's basically an ordered set.

While I could implement this exact algorithm, I don't need this exactly (just the features listed above), and was thinking there's probably something similar out there.

Comment: In Damerau–Levenshtein, the cost of an operation is always 1. Why can't you just modify Damerau–Levenshtein with your cost values?

Comment: I might be able to do that, but I don't know that it's the best solution. For example Damerau-Levenshtein only supports "move" operations (transpose) on adjacent elements. Maybe it'd be trivial to add support for that, but I would prefer something that already exists so that it's efficient (it will get called a lot). Plus my costing idea is rather naive, and I'd prefer something that has been more rigorously explored/reviewed/tested.

Comment: I have no insight on your costing idea, but for actually computing it I'd suggest an A* search to get from one to the other.  So you need both a cost function AND a good lower bound heuristic for the search.